# Python 3.x RAR files extract

Tags: python-3.x, extract, rar

Is it possible to handle RAR files (not ZIP) using **python 3.3**. I already know how to use the ZIP directory, but I didn't find any information about RAR

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [rarfile 2.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/2.2). It has both python 2.7 and python 3.x version according to its features list.